# SQL - Converter string para datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Bom dia,

Procurei de várias maneiras alguma resposta para a minha dúvida, mas não encontrei aqui nenhuma que se adequasse exatamente à minha situação:

Possuo no SQL Server um campo do tipo varchar(17) que guarda um instante no tempo (Ex. '20220223153327939')
Qual seria a forma mais fácil de converter este campo para datetime incluindo milissegundos, ou seja, o resultado pretendia seria: '2022-02-23 15:33:27.939'?

Já tentei diversas variações das funções CAST(), FORMAT() e CONVERT(), mas ainda não encontrei uma solução elegante.

Answer (score -2):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a função Concat para concatenar os caracteres separadores na parte do horário antes da conversão:

```
select 
    convert
        (datetime2, 
         concat
             (left(DataHora, 8),
              ' ',
              substring(DataHora, 9, 2),
              ':',
              substring(DataHora, 11, 2),
              ':',
              substring(DataHora, 13, 2),
              '.',
              right(DataHora, 3)),
         112)
```